# How can I use slug instead of id in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, slug

How can I use slug instead of id in laravel 8

This is my public function in controller

```
public function singleProduct($slug){
        $product = Product::findOrFail($slug);
        return view('frontend.product.product', compact('product'));
    }
```

and this is the route

```
Route::get('/product/{slug}', [HomeController::class, 'singleProduct']);
```

and this is from where it will go to the single product

```
<a href="{{ url('/product/'.$product->slug) }}" class="customBtn4">Read More</a>
```

Comment: `findOrFail()` method accept and `id` , you need to change `$product = Product::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrfail();`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use slug for your route model binding, without changing the primary key of your database table, Laravel provides a method to override the key used for a request with route model binding.
So you could add this to your model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Which would allow you to use it like this:

```
public function singleProduct(Product $product)
{
    return view('frontend.product.product', compact('product'));
}
// 
Route::get('/product/{product}', [HomeController::class, 'singleProduct']);
```

However this will change they route key for every route/request and that might not be what you actually want.
So the even easier way is to specify the model key directly on the route like this:

```
Route::get('/product/{product:slug}', [HomeController::class, 'singleProduct']);
```

Which also allows you to use it in your controller without the extra query:

```
public function singleProduct(Product $product)
//...
```

Comment: `Route::get('/product/{product:slug}', [HomeController::class, 'singleProduct']);` worked out of the box for Laravel 10. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already provides an option to explicitly set the primary key using the `$primaryKey` property in your model class which you can set another column as the primary key other than the default `id` column. More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Now to use `slug` as default instead of `id` as the route path, follow the below steps:

Step 1: Open your `Product.php` model file and set the `$primaryKey`, `$incrementing` and `$keyType` property:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'slug'; // your column name
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

...
```

Step 2: Edit your `singleProduct` method in the `HomeController.php` controller file:

```
public function singleProduct(Product $product)
{
    return view('frontend.product.product', compact('product'));
}
```

That's all. Now you don't need to first find the slug and check if it exists or not. Laravel will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"/"` before the product

```
<a href="{{ url('/product/'.$product->slug) }}" class="customBtn4">Read More</a>
```

so it should be like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('product/'.$product->slug) }}" class="customBtn4">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to resolve Eloquent models using a column other than id you may specify the column in the route parameter definition.

`Route::get('/product/{product:slug}', [HomeController::class, 'single_product']);`

in `routes/web.php`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Models\Product;

// Route definition...
Route::get('/product/{product:slug}', [HomeController::class, 'single_product']);
```

in `HomeController`:

```
// Controller method definition...
public function singleProduct(Product $product)
{
    return view('frontend.product.product', ['product' => $product]);
}
```